# Can't access jenkins from host machine

Tags: virtualbox, centos-7, jenkins

I have created a centos 7 vbox and installed jenkins. my issue here is that I am able to access jenkins on the vbox but I am not able to access jenkins when I ssh into the vbox through terminal. My network settings for vbox are set to NAT and I have already setup port forwarding.

please help.!! :(

Answer (score 0):

BY default ssh feature is disabled, go to manage Jenkins --> global security --> SSH server--> click on sshd Port and enter 22 in port text box.